# Ubuntu 14.04: Suspend, Hibernate and Suspend-hybrid in the menu?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hibernate

I followed the documentation at
https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html 
to enable Hibernate in the menu.
I would like to have ALL three options Suspend, Hibernate and Suspend-hybrid in the menu. Is there a way to achieve that?